# Uso del % en una cadena de Texto

Tags: python

### Uso del % en un string

La pregunta es la siguiente, en el bloque de código que se muestra a continuación:

```python
for img_i in range(1, 11):
    f = '000%03d.jpg' % img_i
    url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cadl/celeb-align/' + f
    print(url, end='\r')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join('img_align_celeba', f))
```

Cual es la función del % que aparece en la linea dos del código 2, ¿Porque a la cadena de texto '000%03d.jpg' se le aplica al modulo junto con la variable img_i?

**NOTA:** El extracto de código es de un programa que muestra imágenes en el navegador.

De ante mano aprecio mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este caso `%` no es el operador módulo dado que su operando es una cadena y no un escalar (ver al final de la pregunta). En este caso `%` actúa como  el operador de formateo de cadenas. Es un método [heredado de C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) para formatear cadenas y que se considera anticuado en la práctica en la actualidad frente a los otros métodos existentes.

Dentro de la cadena se especifica una diana que marca la presencia de un especificador de formato usando el carácter `%` seguido del formato deseado, en este caso `'%03d'`:

- `0` -> bandera que indica que se debe rellenar con ceros a la izquierda para valores numéricos
- `3` -> el numero tendrá al menos 3 dígitos, si tiene menos se rellena con ceros.
- `d` -> decimal con signo (tipo)

En el lado derecho del operador se proporcionan los valores a usar por cada especificador.

Para verlo más claro:

> ```
> >>> "%03d" % 1
> '001'  
> >>> "%03d" % 15
> '015' 
> >>> "%03d" % 155
> '155'
> >>> "%03d" % 15558
> '15558'
> ```

En tu caso concreto lo que hace es generar nombres de archivo de forma dinámica usando un `for` que genera enteros desde 1 hasta 10:

> "000001.jpg"
>   "000002.jpg"
>   ...
>   "000010.jpg"

La sintaxis general es:

```
%[clave][banderas][ancho][.precisión][longitud]tipo de conversión % valores
```

- **%** -> Obligatorio. Indica como se ha comentado una marca o diana en la cadena dónde se debe producir un remplazo y formateo. Marca por tanto el inicio del especificador.
- **clave** -> Opcional. Es una clave de mapeo usada para asociar el valor correcto con ese epecificador.
- **banderas** -> Opcional. Banderas de conversión que permiten modificar el resultado de algunos tipos de conversión.
- **ancho** -> Opcional.  Ancho mínimo de campo. Si se especifica como "*" (asterisco), el ancho real se lee desde el siguiente elemento de la tupla de valores y el objeto a convertir viene después del ancho de campo mínimo y la precisión opcional.
- **precisión** -> opcional. Se especifica mediante un punto "." seguido de la precisión. Si se especifica como "*" , el ancho real se lee desde el siguiente elemento de la tupla de valores y el valor a convertir viene después de la precisión.
- **logitud** -> Opcional. Modificador de longitud.
- **tipo de conversión** -> Opcional
- **valores** -> Obligatorio. Un número, una cadena o un contenedor con valores para sustituir el tipo de conversión.

Algunos ejemplos más:

> ```
> >>> valores = {'a': 1537, "b": 13, "r": 1533 / 13}
> >>> '%(a)d dividido entre %(b)s es %(r).2f' % valores
> 1537 dividido entre 13 es 117.92
> >> '%07.2f' % 3.141592653589793
> '0003.14'
> >>> '%13s' % 'Hola' # Padding
> '         Hola'
> >>> '%+d' % 13
> '+13'
> >>> '%+d' % -13
> '-13'
> >>> "%X" % 2334 # Representacion hexadecimal
> '91E'
> ```

---

En la actualidad hay dos métodos de formato más:

- **[`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#format)/[`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)**:

  > ```
  > >>> "{:03d}".format(15)
  > '015'
  > >>> format(15, "03d")
  > '015'
  > ```
- **[f-strings o literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)**: solo disponibles a partir de Python 3.6. Son una forma muy eficiente (la más eficiente de las tres) de formatear cadenas (literales en este caso) de una forma bastante simple y legible usando una sintaxis básicamente igual a `format()/str.format()`.

  Para declarar un f-string simplemente se antepone una `f` antes de las comillas que delimitan la cadena:

  > ```
  > >>> n = 15
  > >>> f"{n:03d}"
  > '015'
  > ```

Para conocer las posibilidades que ofrecen es importante mirarse [Format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

---

Ten en cuenta que un mismo operador puede actuar de forma distinta dependiendo de los objetos sobre los que opera. No solo ocurre con `%`, sin ir más lejos `+` actúa de forma diferente si tenemos una cadena, un escalar, una lista, etc:

> ```
> >>> "Hola " + "mundo"
> 'Hola mundo'
> >>> 3 + 8
> 11
> >>> [4, 3] + [2, 7]
> [4, 3, 2, 7]
> ```

A esto se le conoce como sobrecarga de operadores. Un ejemplo de una clase propia en la que definimos el método especial [`__mod__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__mod__) que será llamado al usar el operador % sobre instancias de esa clase:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.dic = dic
    def __mod__(self, other):
        return Foo({**self.dic, **other.dic})
```

> ```
> >>> a = Foo({"a": 8, "c": 7})
> >>> b = Foo({"c": 3, "b": 17})
> >>> r = a % b
> >>> r.dic
> {'a': 8, 'c': 3, 'b': 17}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

el % se utiliza como Operador de Formateo de una Cadena (String).
Por ejemplo:

```
>>> " %03d " % 1
'001'
```

En este caso, genera un número de 3 dígitos, en donde lo que hace el '1' al lado del '%' es decirle que forme el número '001'. En tu caso:

```
f = '000%03d.jpg' % img_i
```

Se formarán los números de tres dígitos del 1 al 10. 
000**001**.jpg, 000**002**.jpg, ..., 000**010**.jpg

Fuente: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html

Answer (score 2):

Es una de las formas en la que python puede usar variables en texto, y tiene diversos fines, tales como la administración de archivos que es el caso del ejemplo que planteas, existen varias maneras de hacer esto, una de ellas es con los operadores `%`

```
nombre = "Luis"
edad = 23
cadena = "Hola %s, tu edad es %d" % (nombre, edad)
print(cadena)
```

**Salida**

> 'Hola Luis, tu edad es 23'

Como puedes ver la funcion de `%` podria decirse que es la de remplazar esa parte del texto por alguna variable, y la letra que le sigue indica el tipo de dato a remplazar,

Pero no es la única manera tambien puedes usar llaves `{}`, de esta manera no tienes que definir el tipo de dato que sera usado y a su vez puedes usar ciertos parámetros, usando las mismas variables

```
cadena = "Hola {}, tu edad es {}".format(nombre, edad)
cadena = "Hola {0}, tu edad es {1}".format(nombre, edad)
cadena = "Hola {1}, tu edad es {0}".format(nombre, edad)
cadena = "Hola {nom}, tu edad es {ed}".format(nom = "Alejandro", ed=20)
cadena = f"Hola {nombre}, tu edad es{ed}"
```

Si imprimimos las cadenas las salidas serian las siguientes

**Salida**

> 'Hola Luis, tu edad es 23'
>
> 'Hola Luis, tu edad es 23'
>
> 'Hola 23, tu edad es Luis'
>
> 'Hola Alejandro, tu edad es 20'
>
> 'Hola Luis, tu edad es 23'

En el primer caso no le añadimos parámetros a las llaves y python toma por orden los datos que le asignes a `format()`, o como en el ejemplo 2 y 3, puedes añadir el indice y python lo hara en ese orden, también puedes asignarle un nombre y definirlo después en `format()` como en el ejemplo 4, y por ultimo puedes usar la `f` antes de las comillas y agregar entre llaves el nombre de la variable a usar y asi evitar el uso de `format()`

te comparto esas otras formas de dar formato porque son las mas usadas, en el ejemplo que tu pones ya no es tan utilizado, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es una manera de formatear texto algo anticuada.

```
'%s %s' % ('ejemplo', 'de prueba')

'{} {}'.format('ejemplo', 'de prueba')

f'{ejemplo} {de prueba}'  # Solo a partir de Python 3.6
```

Estos tres ejemplos vienen a hacer lo mismo, formatear una string utilizando variables. Para entender por completo este tema te sugiero que leas https://pyformat.info/